# Java project - Pizza assignment

Tags: java

I just started my education learning Java on first semester and I have my first project right now where the assignment is to make a system for a pizza shop. I have made a Menu class where I made an arraylist called Menu.

So I want the pizza guy to be able to see the whole menu (this part is done) however the assignment also requires the pizza guy to see current orders and add/remove orders. I have already made pizza objects and added them to the Menu in my main class as follows:

```
Pizza vesuvio = new Pizza("Vesuvio",57, 1, "tomatsauce, ost og oregano");
menu.addPizza(vesuvio);
```

Then i have made a userDialogue method in my "Ordering class" where i want to set the pizzaNumber from main equals to the pizza number that the pizza guy enters. And then add the pizza according to the number. So for example let's take the Vesuvio, the number (1) is the pizza's number on the Menu so if the pizza guy enters 1 I want it to add Vesuvio to the current orders.

For now in my ordering class this is my userDialogue

```
private ArrayList<Pizza> orderList = new ArrayList();
public void userDialogue() {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press 1 to add an order\nPress 2 to remove an order");
        int answerDialog = myScan.nextInt();
        if (answerDialog == 1) {
            System.out.println("Type the costumers name");
            costumerName = myScan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Type the pizza's number");
            pizzaNumber = myScan.nextInt(); //These 3 lines is what im confused about. Can 
            if(pizzaFromMenu==pizzaNumber) {
                orderList.addPizza(pizza);
            }
        }
    }
```

To sum it up: can I somehow match the pizza's from the menu with the pizza the customer order somehow?

Comment: You could use `switch` statement  to match what the user has entered to available pizza types.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few potential problems with your code:

1. You need to initialize your ArrayLists using `new ArrayList<>();` instead of `new ArrayList();`
2. I'm a bit confused as to how you're calling `menu.addPizza()` and `orderList.addPizza()` seeing as the two are instances of `ArrayList`, and such a method does not exist in that class. Perhaps use `menu.add()` and `orderList.add()` instead?
3. Instead of assigning each pizza with a number yourself, you can use the pizza's index in `menu`. For example, instead of assigning `vesuvio` as 1, use 0 (it's index in `menu` assuming it was the first one added to the list).

   To add a pizza to `orderList`, you can just call `orderList.add(menu.get(pizzaNumber-1));`. Similarly, to remove use `orderList.remove(menu.get(pizzaNumber-1));`

Now, you can replace

```
if(pizzaFromMenu==pizzaNumber) {
    orderList.addPizza(pizza);
}
```

with

```
orderList.add(menu.get(pizzaNumber-1));
```

Comment: 1. I did it, also added constructor. Looks like this now
```
private ArrayList<Pizza> orderList;
private String costumerName;

    public Orderlist(ArrayList<Pizza> orderList, String costumerName) {
        this.orderList= orderList;
        this.costumerName= costumerName;
        orderList= new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: 2. Was just a type, translating from my original language so i made the mistake. Fixed it now

Comment: 3. Yes but i also need to display the menu like a regular pizza menu in this format:
NumberOfPizza, NameOfPizza, Topping, Price. That's why i gave the pizza's numbers

Also i don't quite understood the last thing you said.
Let's say the costumer types in the number of the pizza in a variable called pizzaChoice, then i want that number to grab the pizza from the menu(without removing it ofc) and put it in the other arraylist called orderList aswell

Comment: If you want to print out the menu in a specific format, simply loop through `menu` and print the information of each pizza object using getters. My point was that `NumberOfPizza` can just be the index of the pizza in `menu`. What its doing is grabbing the pizza object from `menu` based on `pizzaChoice` and adding (or removing) the pizza object from `orderList`. The objects in `menu` will remain unchanged.

Comment: I already made it print the menu. I think i understand it now but where do i put this orderList.add(menu.get(pizzaNumber-1)) In my main?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try replacing that `if` statement with the new line I've given you.

Comment: Yes that seemed to work better! However now i get an error. I don't think it's possible to see the menu now? I made it an public arraylist in my menu class.
https://prnt.sc/pnraec
This is my error message

Comment: Since `menu` is in a different class, make sure that it is initialized and contains all the necessary instances of `Pizza` before accessing it in the main class. Option 1 is to make `menu` a private class member and access it with a getter in `userDialog()`. Option 2 is to move `menu` and its logic into the main class with `orderList`.

Comment: So if you want to use the getter, the code would become `orderList.add(instanceOfMenuClass.getMenu().get(pizzaNumber-1));`

Comment: I now added getter and setter in my Menu class and used the line you just gave me. Now i get this https://prnt.sc/pnrig3

Comment: I edited my comment to fix my typo. Try again with what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the ArrayList method .indexOf()
Say they enter the value 2, call `Pizza choice = menu.indexOf(2)` and then you can do `orders.add(choice)`  or `orders.remove(choice)` depending on their selection. 
Just be careful with the indexes. Remember, index starts at 0. If they choose 2 on the menu, it may be 1 in the ArrayList.

Comment: So the choice needs to be made like this?
```
Pizza choice = myScan.nextInt();
```
Or what do you mean? I don't quite understand. After the customer input a number then that pizza according to the number typed need to be added to the orderList. So somehow it needs to be some way like this:
```
if (NumberFromCustomer equals WhatEverPizza) {
     add the pizza to orderList
}
```

Comment: After you do `int choice = myScan.nextInt()` you should then have something like : `Pizza order = menu.get(choice);` and then `Orders.add(order);` It may make sense to add some sort of check to see if that order actually exists in the menu, too.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the ArrayList in the constructor

```
   private ArrayList<Pizza> orderList;

   public constructor(){
     orderList = new ArrayList();
    }
    public void userDialogue() {
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press 1 to add an order\nPress 2 to remove an order");
    int answerDialog = myScan.nextInt();
    if (answerDialog == 1) {
        System.out.println("Type the costumers name");
        costumerName = myScan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Type the pizza's number");
        pizzaNumber = myScan.nextInt(); 
        if(pizzaFromMenu==pizzaNumber) {
            orderList.addPizza(pizza);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide as part of your answer a short meaningful description of how your code snippet answers the question.

Comment: Thank you. Did that now

Comment: @samoussa.usa I don't understand haha, im brand new:P